# How can I pass multiple Nashorn arguments when I launch a jar?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn, jjs

I am trying to pass multiple Nashorn arguments when I start a jar, something like this:

```
java -Dnashorn.args=-scripting -t -jar myjar.jar
```

The second Nashorn argument -t doesn't seem to be processed, and I get this:

```
Unrecognized option: -Xt
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I guess it was considered to be a java argument but that was not my intention, how can I clearly state that it's a Nashorn argument and not a java one?

Note: I'm using java version "1.8.0_144"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think comma separated values work. I looked at the relevant nashorn source code. It uses StringTokenizer with the default delimiter set (which is  " \t\n\r\f"). So the following works:

```
java -Dnashorn.args="-scripting -t=Asia/Calcutta" -jar myjar.jar
```

Note that with -t option, a timezone argument has to be passed.